# Crear elementos en tiempo de ejecución

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estoy creando un sistema de ordenes, mi problema esque las ordenes creadas en tiempo de ejecucion no puedo moverlas a otros div. En cambion si simplemente la inserto en mi codigo html funciona perfecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Estaba utilizando:

```
          html = '<div style="opacity: 1;" class="todo-task ui-sortable-handle">';
          html += '<div class="task-header">';
          html += '<div class="task-no">30</div>';
          html += '<div class="task-type">Action</div>';
          html += '</div>';
          html += '<div class="task-body">';
          html += '<div class="task-title">Meet with technical teams to discuss solution</div>';
          html += '</div>';
          html += '<div class="task-footer">';
          html += '<div class="task-date">Due: 17/07/2012</div>';
          html += '</div>';
          html += '</div>';
          $('#backlog').append(html);
```

pero no es la forma correcta ya que no me respeta varias cosas al trabajar con dichos elementos.

```
function loadlink(){
  url='<?=  site_url("datos/getdatos")?>', 
  $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: url, 
    beforeSend: function () {

    },
      success: function(result){
        var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(result);


        if(parsedJSON.length != elements.length){
          elements = [];
          for (var i=0;i<parsedJSON.length;i++) {
              //Crear etiqueta nueva con el codigo de arriba
          }
        }
    }
  });
}
```

como seria desde jquery para crear elementos en tiempo de ejecución, con las clases que se encuentran en mi primer codigo, espero y me puedan ayudar. Saludos!

Codigo JS

```
var $container = $(".task-container");
var $task = $('.todo-task');

$task.draggable({
    addClasses: false,
    connectToSortable: ".task-container",
});

$container.droppable({
    accept: ".todo-task"
});


$(".ui-droppable").sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    opacity: .5,
    helper: 'original',
    beforeStop: function (event, ui) {
        newItem = ui.item;
    },
    receive: function (event, ui) {
//get task-type and task id.
            var tasktype = $(this).find('.task-type').html();
            var taskid = $(this).find('.task-no').html();
    console.log(taskid);
    console.log(tasktype);

            dropElement = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(dropElement);
            // console.log($(this).closest('.ui-droppable').attr('id'));

            //save the status and the order of the item.
            if (dropElement == "backlog")
            {
                // save the status of the item
            }
            else if (dropElement == "pending")
            {
                // save the status of the 
            }
            else if (dropElement == "inProgress")
            {
            }
            else if (dropElement == "completed")
            {
            }
    }
}).disableSelection().droppable({
    over: ".ui-droppable",
    activeClass: 'highlight',
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
    }
});
```

html:

```
    <div class="task-list task-container ui-droppable ui-sortable ui-state-highlight col-sm-3" id="backlog">
<!--Agregarlo directamente si funciona-->
             <div class="todo-task ui-sortable-handle">
                <div class="task-header">
                    <div class="task-no">61</div>
                    <div class="task-type">Action</div>
                </div>
                <div class="task-body">
                    <div class="task-title">Etiqueta directamente insertada</div>
                </div>
                <div class="task-footer">
                    <div class="task-date">Due: 12/06/2014</div>
                </div>
          </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: Cual es el inconveniente? Luego de crear dinamicamente los elementos ya no te es posible encontrarlos con `$('.nombre-clase')`?

Comment: si pero por alguna razon no me funciona _drag and drop_ con _jquery-ui_ al crearlos de forma dinamica, insertarlos directamente funciona perfecto. Supuse que el problema viene de ahí

Comment: No se exactamente tu caso, pero talvez `.on()` [de jquery](http://api.jquery.com/on/) te podria funcionar. Ejemplo: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click)

Comment: Utilizo esto [Jquery-ui](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/) creo que en ningùn momento debe usar `.on()`

Answer (score 1):

A ver si entendi.

Cuando tienes tu codigo fijo en HTML funciona lo de arrastrar y cuando insertas elementos de forma dinamica ¿no le aplica esa funcialidad ?

Independientemente de como agreges los elementos al DOM, JQuery ya no les aplica los eventos que hayas inicializado con anterioridad, tendrías que llamar de nuevo a la función donde asignaste los eventos.

Te pongo un ejemplo donde pongo un Div con la clase draggable (basandome en el ejemplo de la [documentacion](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/)) y en la función de inicialización de JQ hago que los objetos (al inicio solo uno) con la clase draggable les asigne el evento `draggable()`.

Tambien hay dos botones que agregan Div's con la clase draggable, un boton los crea como string y otro como objetos JQ, sin embargo a ninguno de ellos los puedes arrastrar hasta que invocas de nuevo a `$( ".draggable" ).draggable();` que se ejecuta cuando haces click en el boton "Aplicar draggable"

```js
$( function() {
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable();
  } );
  
  
  function add(){
  $("#area").append( $("<div class='draggable'>Draggable agregado</div>") );
  }

  function addJQ(){
  $("#area").append( $("<div>").addClass("draggable").text("Draggable JQ") );
  }
  
  function aplicar(){
   $( ".draggable" ).draggable();
  }
```

```css
.draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="button" onclick="add()" value="Agregar div">
<input type="button" onclick="addJQ()" value="Agregar div con JQ">
<input type="button" onclick="aplicar()" value="Reaplicar draggable">

<div id="area">
  <div class="draggable">
    Draggable Inicial
  </div>
 </div>
```

**EDITADO**
En tu JS las dos primeras lineas capturan una lista de elementos Jquery basado en los selectores `".task-container"` y `'.todo-task'`

```
var $container = $(".task-container");
var $task = $('.todo-task');
```

Lo que significa que $container y $task siempre van a tener los mismos elementosaunque agregues mas al DON, recuerda que los objetos JQuery se generan al momento y no pertenecen al árbol DOM, es decir si llamas dos veces al mismo selector, este te regresará dos objetos diferentes que contienen el mismo nodo DOM

```
var a = $("#elemento")
var b = $("#elemento")
// a y b serán objetos diferentes 
//aunque hagan referencia al mismo elemento del DOM con el id= elemento
```

Lo que tendrías que hacer es ejecutar de nuevo todo tu JS, pero sin el var de $container y $task

```
//Se capturan de nuevo todos los elementos
$container = $(".task-container"); //Sin el var
$task = $('.todo-task'); //Sin el var

//Le aplicas los mismos eventos
$task.draggable({.......
$container.droppable({.....
$(".ui-droppable").sortable({.....
```

Comment: Agregue mi codigo de como lo tengo en js, me puedes ayudar a identificar como aplicar nuevamente el draggable

Comment: otra cosa entre elementos en lista si puedo moverlos, mi problema es al cambiar de contener